# Cannot build Legacy SIL blocks using MinGW Toolchain in R2016b

Tags: matlab, mingw, simulink

I'm currently upgrading an old project to Matlab R2016b (from R2010bSP1).

In this project we used a workflow in which certain components were compiled into S-functions using the SIL-block functionality in order to speed up simulations and mask IP-property during distribution.

Now; upgrading to R2016b - this does not work anymore.

The included LCC compiler is no longer capable to perform these kinds of builds. The MinGW (free) compiler is suggested as a replacement.

After installing the MinGW toolchain (which has some issues in itself, but those are nicely indicated by Mathworks) I can use this toolchain to build normal SIL blocks (or any other RTW build) without any issue.

**However; when using "silblocktype('legacy')" the MinGW toolchain is no longer recognized. I get "An installed compiler was not detected."...**

NB: issuing silblocktype('legacy') is the ONLY difference between a build that properly reports MinGW being used and one issuing this error.

I uninstalled and reinstalled MinGW as administrator as well as user, no difference.

MinGW files are read/executable for all users on machine.

Could anyone confirm build of SIL legacy blocks using the MinGW toolchain?

Comment: Confirmed by MathWorks support as a bug. I'm awaiting an update. If I get it I will post details. If anyone has a workaround in the meantime I'd be delighted to know it!

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks provided us with a patch to resolve the problem.

If anyone requires it; please contact the Swedish MathWorks office and refer to a patch supplied on 2017-03-13 for "S-Function SIL MinGW" issues.

MathWorks did not at this time indicate whether the fix would be included in later versions since the S-function building style is tagged as "Legacy". Therefore the problem may persist for versions later than R2016b.